# How to pass variable value in @retryable annotation

Tags: rest, configuration, static, annotations, spring-retry

I am using spring retry mechanism when calling rest API.
Using below annotation

```
 @Retryable(value = Exception.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
```

I have a java file using @Configuration which is getting properties from a properties file.
Instead of passing a static value, is there a way I can pass value from the above mentioned java file.

unable to use `@PropertySource("classpath:retryConfig.properties")` as I am getting values from java class and not properties file.

seeing below error when trying to pass an variable

```
The value for annotation attribute Retryable.maxAttempts must be a constant expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `...expression` variants of the properties; here is an example from one of the test cases...

```java
@Retryable(exceptionExpression = "#{@exceptionChecker.${retryMethod}(#root)}",
            maxAttemptsExpression = "#{@integerFiveBean}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${one}}",
                    maxDelayExpression = "#{${five}}", multiplierExpression = "#{${onePointOne}}"))
public void service3() {
```

where `one` and `five` and `onePointOne` are properties.